# Jacobi Elliptic Functions built from Jacobi theta functions

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, elliptic-functions, theta-functions

I believe I understand the general theory of elliptic functions to an extent.

What I can't seem to find is the distinct method which was used to show that a particular combination of Jacobi Theta functions defined any specific elliptic function.

So my question is, how would I go about defining Weierstrass-$\wp$, $\text{sn}, \text{cn}$, or $\text{dn}$ elliptic functions in terms of Jacobi elliptic functions. Reference material or direct answers would help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For a basic treatment of elliptic functions I strongly recommend you the book [Theory of Functions of a Complex Variable by A.I. Markushevich](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/082183780X). Especially take a look at part III chapters 5 and 6. Chapter 5 is a complete treatment on Weierstrass theory, meanwhile chapter 6 introduces Jacobi's theory and the relation to the Weierstrass one.

Here is a screen shot from what is cover on the book

[image]

Comment: Looks like it might be a good book, but $40 and several day waiting for shipping wasn't what i had in mind. I was hoping for some online book or article. Thanks, i might see if any libraries in my area have it in stock tomorrow

Comment: Actually a quick google book search and I found a great preview, Thanks. ^.^

Comment: @T.Poindexter Glad I could help. That book is a classic and I really like the treatment of elliptic functions done there, it covers up pretty much all you must know about them

Comment: from the Weierstrass $\sigma$ functions  for  $\Im(\tau) > 0$ they obtain $S_\tau(z)$ an entire function such that $S_\tau(z+1)=  S_\tau(z),e^{-i\pi \tau} S_\tau(z+\tau) =e^{2i \pi z}  S_\tau(z)$ and its Fourier series is easily shown to be $S_\tau(z) = a_\tau(0)+a_\tau(0) e^{2i \pi n z}\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-i \pi n^2 \tau} e^{2i \pi n z} = \frac{a_\tau(0)}{2} + \frac{a_\tau(0)}{2} \vartheta(-\tau,z)$. The constant term is found from analyticity in $\tau$